# “cd” does'nt work in a scripting in Ubuntu

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, scripting

I'm trying to write a command  `mytodo` to change the current directory to my project directory and saved in /bin/  & changed its permission to executable :

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /vagrant/backup/toDoApp/
```

Earlier it was working wherever or whenever i run `mytodo` it changes my directory to 
/vagrant/backup/toDoApp/ but now suddenly it stopped working now it doesnt changed my cwd.
as i also tried `alias` but when shutdown or restart machine my alias commands disappears
Please help.

Comment: You need to save your alias to your profile script (`$HOME/.bashrc` probably) if you want it to persist, like other bash things.

Comment: Hey Mat that page didnt solved my problem alias is alternative but why my command is not working ?